# Refit requires Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded]) but not required with httpclient

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, refit

I have encountered an issue with refit that took few hours to work out on why calls using refit would result in 403 forbidden whilst using httpclient is fine.
This happens on some servers but not on others.

To Make it work I had to use [Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)].
Cannot work it out why is required though..

I tried all sorts BodySerializationMethod - and googled to see if someone else had encountered the same issue but could not find anything..

any explanations?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Froodo this only happens with our servers and there is no much more to say that works  with Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded) - so not sure if its a server setup or else... but works with httpclient